# Adobe Premiere Pro no H265 export option?

Tags: premiere, adobe, h265, hevc

I am using the trial version of Adobe Premier Pro (also tried Elements) and I noticed that there is no option to export as H265. Is there something i should do in order to enable this functionality? Seems really strange that this is not supported, especially for such a suppoded high-end video editing application.

I am running the following specs:

- OS: Windows 10
- CPU: i7 11700K
- GPU: RTX 3070
- RAM: 32GB DDR4 @ 3200mhz

Answer (score 1):

It should be there, "HEVC (H.265)", selectable under format. If it's not there the codec may not be installed on your system. Adobe describes how to check and install it here: https://helpx.adobe.com/in/premiere-elements/using/hevc-decoding-on-windows.html

Comment: I have the same issue - no HEVC export option, and the codec is installed on my system. It also happens that the decode works just fine, as my source videos are HEVC. But there doesn't seem to be an HEVC Format while exporting.